# Is there a dialog to choose a database?

Tags: database, user-interface, database-connection

Windows already contains dialogs to choose a file or printer.

Is there a built-in dialog to select a database?

Ideally, it would work for databases other than SQL server and would expose a connection string.

Comment: No,​​​​​ there isn't.   However, this is not a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. The printer and file dialogs are baked into the operating system. Database not so much. The Data Sources (ODBC) isn't really something I thought you could call from code easily and I don't think it returns a connectionstring like you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's buried in the 'Administrative Tools':   Start => Control Panel => Administrative Tools => Data Sources(ODBC)

Comment: Ideally, I would like to avoid ODBC. Also, how can I call it from code?

Comment: This wouldn't give you a dialog that you can embed in code somewhere. I think you'd have to hand write something.